# PHP Server Request Method

Tags: php, forms, iframe

I have a form in one file that I submit using method POST.  In the file to the form action, I use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`, but doing a var dump of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` shows `'GET'`.

Any idea how this could be happening?  The form is within an iframe with `src = 'targetfile.php?id=30'` so the code looks something like this:

```
<iframe src="targetfile.php?id=30">
    <form method="post" action="targetfile.php" target="credit_results">
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="hidden_pid" value="30" />
        <input type="text" class="std_grey" name="first_name_info" id="first_name_info"/>
    </form>
    <iframe name="credit_results" id="credit_results" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="960" height="1200"></iframe>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Check if you have both GET and POST values (you also pass a get param in the iframe). I haven't work a lot with iframes...

Comment: Is the var_dump() showing 'GET' when the iframe first loads, as should be expected, and in a log some how when the form submits back to itself?

Comment: `targetfile.php` is being used in both GET and POST contexts. The iframe is requesting the file with GET but it also submits to itself. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because targetfile.php is getting both GET and POST due to the fact that its posting back to itself and originally loaded with a GET query, I would recommend changing your php to check for specific $_POST variables instead of the `REQUEST_METHOD`.

For debugging a `var_dump( $_POST );` should show things are there.

For actual use

```
if( !isset( $_POST['varYouNeed'] )) die( 'Missing varYouNeed variable' );
```

Comment: that's what I would have thought but the $_POST variable is coming back empty

Comment: The $_POST variable is empty when the iframe first loads AND when the form submits back to itself? Can you show us more of html from the iframe and form?

Comment: yes in both cases the GET variable is shown but not the POST vars from the form

Comment: I put this up http://mattw.co/playground/6916699.php. The only php is on targetfile.php in the form which is <?php echo 'GET: '; var_dump( $_GET ); echo 'POST: '; var_dump( $_POST ); ?>

Comment: Thanks, sorry the code was right, there was a redirection in my program.

Answer (score -2):

change:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'
```

to

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'
```